# troubleshooting python module pywinauto

Tags: pycharm, python-3.7, pywinauto

i am running pycharm for developing a basic automation tool for my self i made my research and found a couple of modules the one i want to use is [pywinauto](https://pypi.org/project/pywinauto/) on the pypi site it says that it supports python2.7 up to python3.7 i installed pywinauto package in pycharm with python3.7 system interpreter everything is good so far

for me this pywinauto module is new so i went to the docs and made a simple script to open notepad for me to play around with this module

```
import os
import random
import sys
import time
from pywinauto.application import Application




def get_app(app_name):
    app = Application().start(app_name)
    #app.UntitledNotepad.menu_select("Help->About Notepad")
    pass



if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ("hello world !")
    get_app(app_name="notrpad.exe")
```

But for some reason pycharm gives me an attribute error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/myname/Desktop/winfuzz/winfuxx.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pywinauto.application import Application
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from . import findwindows
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import controls
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from . import uiawrapper # register "uia" back-end (at the end of uiawrapper module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uiawrapper.py", line 47, in <module>
    from ..uia_defines import IUIA
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 181, in <module>
    pattern_ids = _build_pattern_ids_dic()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 169, in _build_pattern_ids_dic
    if hasattr(IUIA().ui_automation_client, cls_name):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 50, in __call__
    cls._instances[cls] = super(_Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 63, in __init__
    self.ui_automation_client.CUIAutomation().IPersist_GetClassID(),
AttributeError: module 'comtypes.gen.UIAutomationClient' has no attribute 'CUIAutomation'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

i tried using python2.7 in pycharm and it just won't install the package some kind of error about ssl certificate

no big deal since i am planning on using python3.7

i also tried using cmd and the notepad for writing the same script but was not successful and i got the same error

Comment: You need to clean up the `comtypes` cache. The script for it should be placed here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Scripts` Also please make sure you're running the script as Administrator (at least the first time, next runs the library will warn you about it properly).

Answer (score 2):

Please correct the spelling of notepad it will work fine.

```
   get_app(app_name="notepad.exe")
```